# How to remove outlook add-ins dialogbox's address bar and custome address bar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am making outllok add-ins and it has dialog box but on address bar it show url that I am passing in displayDialogAsync methode but I don't want that to show the url, i want to make custom address bar how I can I do it ? any idea?. Here is pic of dialog box that open

[image]

here is code for dialog

```
  let dialog;

     const click = async item => {
     var url = `${DEXTA_BASE_URL}/dialog.html#/document/${item.id}`
     var options = { height: 50, width: 30, displayInIframe: true };
      Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, options, result => {
      dialog = result.value;
      dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, 
  receiveMessage);
     });

   };
```

Comment: Where is the source code for the dialog window?

Comment: I have updated the code please check if it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The URL is displayed in the dialog box's title bar as a security measure.